# Problems using spherecluster package for spherical k-mean clustering

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, unsupervised-learning

I am working with data from an accelerometer which can be in different orientations. The data lies on the surface of a sphere. I wish to identify clusters on the surface using spherical k-means clustering.

I installed the package [spherecluster](https://github.com/jasonlaska/spherecluster) from Jason Laska. I was able to install the package without any problems in my Anaconda environment (base and a virtual environment). But when trying to import the spherecluster module I get the following error.

```
(base) ➜  unsupervised_learning: python
Python 3.9.12 (main, Apr  5 2022, 01:52:34)
[Clang 12.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import spherecluster
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spherecluster/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .spherical_kmeans import SphericalKMeans
  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spherecluster/spherical_kmeans.py", line 7, in <module>
    from sklearn.cluster.k_means_ import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.cluster.k_means_'
>>>
```

I have numpy and scipy installed as required by the module. I am not able to find sklearn.cluster.k_means_ The following are my versions of numpy, scipy, and scikit-learn

```
numpy                     1.21.5           py39h25ab29e_1
numpy-base                1.21.5           py39h974a1f5_1
scikit-learn              1.0.2            py39h9197a36_1
scipy                     1.7.3            py39h2f0f56f_0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problems for (pip 22.3 and scikit-learn 1.1.2) what I have to do is to manually edit the script in **spherical_kmeans.py**. I changed these things:

```
from sklearn.cluster.k_means_ import (
    _check_sample_weight,
    _init_centroids,
    _labels_inertia,
    _tolerance,
    _validate_center_shape,
)
```

to

```
from sklearn.cluster._kmeans import (
    _check_sample_weight,
    _labels_inertia,
    _tolerance,
)
```

Then from this:

```
from sklearn.cluster import _k_means
```

To:

```
from sklearn.cluster import _kmeans
```

Line 17 from this:

```
from sklearn.externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed
```

To this:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
```

Line 42 from this:

```
centers = _init_centroids(
        X, n_clusters, init, random_state=random_state, x_squared_norms=x_squared_norms
    )
```

To:

```
centers = KMeans._init_centroids(
        X, n_clusters, init, random_state=random_state, x_squared_norms=x_squared_norms
    )
```

Line 159 from this:

```
_validate_center_shape(X, n_clusters, init)
```

To this:

```
KMeans._validate_center_shape(X, n_clusters, init)
```

Then it worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and had to manually edit the *spherical_kmeans.py* file. I changed this:

```
from sklearn.cluster import _k_means_fast as _k_means
```

for this:

```
from sklearn.cluster import _k_means_common as _k_means
```

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually many issues in running the spherical k means package due to lot of conflicts between the latest sklearn and the sklearn that is assumed in spherical clustering package. I had to manually edit the spherical clustering files but still could not get it to run due to cython issues. The main issue arises from the fact that spherical clustering is using internal files and methods of sklearn which have long been deprecated and some of them do not even exist in the current sklearn main branch. The best suggestion would be to create a venv with the correct dependencies which I believe is 0.22 version of sklearn.